# What is the essence of orthogonal transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

In linear algebra, some author defined orthogonal transformation to be a function that is "inner-product preserving". Some authors define it to be "length-preserving." However, the word isometry is also length-preserving, as can seen by its name(iso="equal"; metry="metric", means length). So is orthogonal transformation the same as isometry? Or is isometry not only used in inner product space, but also more general space? Which definition is more ideal, capturing the essence that we want a so-called orthogonal transformation be? I also saw some people defined it to be a linear transformation that maps to orthnormal basis to orthonormal sets of vectors.

Answer (score 1):

An orthogonal transformation of an inner product space is linear and preserves the inner product. As you said, an isometry is a more general notion as it can be defined in any metric space. The theorem is that orthogonal transformations are precisely linear isometries in the inner product space. The reason is that in such a space, the distance is defined by the norm and the inner product can be retrieved from the norm by using the polarization identity.

Comment: Thanks. While isometry exists in other space, is inner-product preserving function used outside in linear algebra? Hmm.. If I truly want to figure out which capture the essence that a orthogonal transformation be, inner-product vs. length preserving vs. distance preserving, which is more close?

Comment: Yes. See the concept of [conformal map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map), which is part of Complex Analysis.